# How to correctly Implement Android-Async-Http Library into my Applications?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-networking, android-async-http

I am looking for some advice into design methodologies on how to best implement the Android-Async-Http library found here: [Link](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http)

I have used this library in the past, and it has worked really well for me, However I have come into some small issues with it, which I believe can be solved by changing the way I implement it.

The issue which I was having, is if I made a request and the async call back is run when my activity is no longer active (due to a user closing it) and the Error message / content being displayed throws an error as it cant actually access the Activity at that moment as it is no longer available. However that issue is not the main concern of this question and is due to the fact that I am try to access UI in the async callback.

While looking around for some solutions to my issue, I was given the following proposal:

> @Zapnologica you basically don't want to rely on UI/Context presence when implementing callback. 
>   Far more better design is to use Service, which does whatever is required with the returned data and then notify (broadcast Intent or use ServiceConnection) listeners (eg. your activity/fragment implementation), where the broadcast will have no effect if the context is already not present or the fragment is in invisible/deactivated state.

Now this brought me to the idea that I am implementing the library incorrectly. Currently I have a static instance of a the `HttpClient` which I then call from my activities / fragments. I then execute the corresponding code in the library's async call backs, (As the callbacks are run on the calling activities thread). Here is an example below:

```
Network.Post(getApplicationContext(), URL, RequestParams, new  public AsyncHttpResponseHandler  {     

        @Override
        public void onStart() {             
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
          UpdateListviewAdapter(ParseNetworkResponse(response));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
            Toast.makeToast("Error", Toast.LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Now this implementation is adequate and it does the job. However I am starting a new app and I would like to start from scratch and implement the library best as possible so that I donot encouter issues furtherdown the line. I like the points which where given to me by [smarek](https://github.com/smarek) in the quoted text above.

- Use a Service
- Broadcast Intent or use ServiceConnection to Relay response back to Activty

I would like to find out more about these two suggestions.

I like the Idea of using a service to make the network requests, this way it separates the implementation of the actual network request from all of the Activities and Fragments, and I am able to do possible processing  such as parsing JSON , Error Handling etc in a different thread. Therefore Removing load from the UI thread which is good. However I do have some concerns with what I have read about services, and that is:

1. That Android can close / terminate a service at any time if it needs to clean up resources. If this happens will my app loose connectivity? Or will android not close services being used by currently running Applications?
2. Do I put my Static Instance of the library `HttpCLient` in the service? How do I go about doing this?

Would the activity contact my "NetworkignService" and tell it that I want to make a request to X url and pass through to it the needed parameters. That service will then go and make the network request, wait for the response, and then process that response. Being it an Error or a Successful response. Would I then I have defined a public Method in my Activity which the service will call, giving it the responses data exactly as I need it? All I then need to do on the UI is display the data?

I am looking to achieve the following:

- Centralised Code / Access to the implementation of the library.
- Centralised error handling for network requests
- Remove as much load from the UI thread as possible
- Make it as dynamic and extendible so that I can possible reuse the Networking server / implementation in multiple projects.
- Be able to make Http Request from An Activity, Fragment or other services / classes in my application.

Please can I get your advice and suggestions on the proposed solution and possibly mentioning a better solution? Basically what I am looking for is a good design pattern / principle in which I can make network requests from my Activity's and Fragments.

Comment: why do not use volley? it can handle all of your issues or it can give you all great ideas you want? you can configure it and it can behave in a way you like.

Comment: Care to explain further on that? What exactly is Volley? Where can I get more information on it? I gave it a quick Google and several things appeared. Could you please clarify to what you are referring.

Comment: volley is an open source google library that uses threads to implement network request asynchronously, it can fetch data from server in any format like json image and son on.